Is there a way to create a list of values from a function and then make those values into a histogram in R? I keep getting NA
I am new to the language R. I have a function and am trying to make a list that uses that function to create 1000 entries to the list, to then make a histogram.
This is my code that I have tried:
for (i in 1:1000)
   zscores[i] <- Reduce("+", runif(12)) - 6
hist(zscores)

I am getting an number for i[1] and i[1000], but for all the other entries I get NA when I should be getting a number. What am I doing wrong?

Just a note that Reduce("+", runif(12)) is an obtuse (and inefficient) way to write sum(runif(12))

where is the code that sets up zscores? that also looks like python code

How would you suggest I set up zscores ?

I didn't get any NAs running your code this way
zscores <- c()
for (i in 1:1000) {
  zscores[i] <- Reduce("+", runif(12)) - 6
}
hist(zscores)

Or running the way Gregor Thomas mention
zscores <- c()
for (i in 1:1000) {
  zscores[i] <- sum(runif(12)) - 6
}
hist(zscores)



Yes! Thank you. I didn't put zscores <- c() before, which is what I did wrong I believe.

@user24121912 R won't run the loop without the brackets either
